# Flash application's task bar button?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, taskbar

With Delphi 10 Seattle, I've tried to make the application's Windows taskbar button flash using this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FlashWindow(Application.Handle, True); 
end;
```

or:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Flash: FLASHWINFO;
begin
  FillChar(Flash, SizeOf(Flash), 0);
  Flash.cbSize := SizeOf(Flash);
  Flash.hwnd := Application.Handle;
  Flash.dwFlags := FLASHW_ALL or FLASHW_TIMER;
  Flash.dwTimeout := 1000;
  FlashWindowEx(Flash);
end;
```

or:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Flash: FLASHWINFO;
begin
  FillChar(Flash, SizeOf(Flash), 0);
  Flash.cbSize := SizeOf(Flash);
  Flash.hwnd := Application.Handle;
  Flash.uCount := 5;
  Flash.dwTimeOut := 2000;
  Flash.dwFlags := FLASHW_ALL;
  FlashWindowEx(Flash);  
end;
```

OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1

Unfortunately, this does not work: The task bar button does not flash at all.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your .dpr file you will see the following line:

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True;
```

What this means is that the window associated with the taskbar button is that of the main form. And not that of the `Application` object. So in your code, pass `Application.MainFormHandle` to `FlashWindow` or `FlashWindowEx`.

Comment: David, many thanks! Thanks also for the explanation! Do you know whether there are any UI guidelines for how fast the blinking should be?

Comment: Not sure about flashing rate. I'd look and see if you can find the rate that ms apps use. 1s frequency feels right.